# Connecting Master View and Detail View in UISplitView

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I'm having trouble getting my split view app working correctly.  I'm not able to get anything to show up in the detail view when a row in the master view is tapped.  Here is what I have right now.  I'm at a total loss at this point because I can't figure this out.  I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

**App Delegate.h**

```
//
//  KFBAppDelegate.h
//  KYFB
//
//  Created by KFB on 1/15/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KFBAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
//
//  KFBAppDelegate.m
//  KYFB
//
//  Created by KFB on 1/15/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import "KFBAppDelegate.h"
#import "KFBMasterViewController.h"
#import "KFBDetailViewController.h"

@implementation KFBAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    KFBMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[KFBMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBMasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

    KFBDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[KFBDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = @[masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

**MasterViewController.h**

```
//
//  KFBMasterViewController.h
//  KYFB
//
//  Created by KFB on 1/15/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class KFBDetailViewController;

@interface KFBMasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) KFBDetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
//
//  KFBMasterViewController.m
//  KYFB
//
//  Created by KFB on 1/15/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import "KFBMasterViewController.h"
#import "KFBDetailViewController.h"
#import "SocialNetworks.h"

@interface KFBMasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
    NSMutableArray *menu;
}
@end

@implementation KFBMasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    menu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Home", @"Public Affairs", @"Action Alerts", @"Market Updates", @"Ag Stories", @"KFB News", @"Member Benefits", @"Monthly Video", @"Photos", @"Social Media", @"About Us", @"Contact Us", @"KYFB.com", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return menu.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    // NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    // cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    cell.textLabel.text = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    // self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;

    // KFBDetailViewController *detailViewController = (KFBDetailViewController*)self.splitViewController.delegate;

    // UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController = nil;

    if (indexPath.row == 9)
    {
        if (!self.detailViewController)
        {
            self.detailViewController = (KFBDetailViewController*)[[SocialNetworks alloc]initWithNibName:@"SocialNetworks" bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

**SocialNetworks.h**

```
//
//  SocialNetworks.h
//  KFBNewsroom
//
//  Created by Adam Rayborn on 10/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "KFBDetailViewController.h"

@interface SocialNetworks : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**SocialNetworks.m**

```
//
//  SocialNetworks.m
//  KFBNewsroom
//
//  Created by Adam Rayborn on 10/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 com.kfb. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SocialNetworks.h"

@interface SocialNetworks ()

@end

@implementation SocialNetworks
{
    NSMutableArray *mbTableData;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    mbTableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Facebook", @"Twitter", @"YouTube", nil];
    self.title = @"Social Networks";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [mbTableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *mbTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:mbTableIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }

    // cell.backgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    // cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[CustomCellBackground alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = [mbTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithNibName:@"Facebook" bundle:[NSBundle  mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:facebook animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        Twitter *twitter = [[Twitter alloc] initWithNibName:@"Twitter" bundle:[NSBundle  mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:twitter animated:YES];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        YouTube *youTube = [[YouTube alloc] initWithNibName:@"YouTube" bundle:[NSBundle  mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:youTube animated:YES];
    }
    */

}


@end
```

Comment: I would create a new blank project and select master/detail project and see how they do it. It's setup exactly the way you need.

Comment: That's what I did.  I've added the SocialNetworks view but can't seem to make it show in the detail view when selecting that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in your code, in your `MasterViewController` class, you seem to be pushing the `DetailViewController` to your `MasterViewController`'s navigation controller.

I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do. Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 9)
    {
        [((UINavigationController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject]) pushViewController:[[SocialNetworks alloc]initWithNibName:@"SocialNetworks" bundle:nil] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a "No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushNavigationController:animated:'"

Comment: Wow, I just realized that I wrote `pushNavigationController` instead of `pushViewController`. Sorry about that!

Comment: I probably should have noticed that as well.  Shame on both us us.  The solution worked though, so thanks a ton!

Comment: The only problem I'm seeing with this is when using it in portrait, you have to hit the back button on the nav bar to get back to the master view.  It should be where you can select the master view at any point, shouldn't it?